# SharePoint 2016 FBA Error

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, forms-authentication

I create a web application in SharePoint 2016 and extended that web application to internet zone with form based authentication. When i am trying to log in with the user below error is coming in Logs."The fullName was not a claims user name as the provider was unknown. FullName: 'mymembershipprovider:0#.f|mymembershipprovider|saad'"

```
11/18/2017 12:50:39.67  w3wp.exe (0x0904)                           0x3658  SharePoint Foundation           User Key                        ax8l9   Medium      ContentService is set to not use user key. User: 'saad'.    29312e9e-e04e-1071-aafc-adb85b017066
11/18/2017 12:50:39.67  w3wp.exe (0x0904)                           0x3658  SharePoint Foundation           User Key                        ayswp   High        Successfully got user key for user. User key and userNameSuffix are identical. UserNameSuffix: '0#.f|mymembershipprovider|saad'.    29312e9e-e04e-1071-aafc-adb85b017066
11/18/2017 12:50:39.67  w3wp.exe (0x0904)                           0x3658  SharePoint Foundation           User Key                        ax8m2   Unexpected  The fullName was not a claims user name as the provider was unknown. FullName: 'mymembershipprovider:0#.f|mymembershipprovider|saad'    29312e9e-e04e-1071-aafc-adb85b017066
```

Any idea? what's i am doing wrong?

Followed this article for form based authentication: https://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2016-part-2-editing-the-web-config-files/

Comment: [crosspost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47378074/1699210)